# Replicate On-Premises Hyper-V VM to Microsoft Azure (ASR)

Tags: azure, replication

Below is the diagram of my on-premises site connected to Azure site via S2S IPsec VPN. 
[On-premises and Azure Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xejz1.jpg)

I got several questions and woul highly appreciate if someone could clarify them for me.

1) Can replicated virtual machine retain it's original IP address (172.28.10.1)after failover occurs?

2) My virtual domain controller has 2vCPU AMD Opteron 4171 HE \ 4GB RAM and 3 VHDX disks. What would be the configuration of that domain controller after it is replicated to Azure and which disks will be replicated?

3) At the moment on-premises site is connected with Azure site via Site-to-Site IPsec VPN tunnel. Once on-premises virtual machines are replicated and failover occurs both sites will be on Azure. How do I connect them to each other?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for your reply. For now I use Virtual Network Gateway to connect on-premises site and Azure site. When failover occurs, both sites will be on Azure and they should be connected with VNet-to-VNet connection. Now question is, how do I switch between S2S IPsec VPN and VNet2VNet connections?

Answer (score 0):

1) Depends. It's not possible to integrate networks if they overlap, so if you already have S2S in place, that means your Azure network and on-prem network don't have the same IP address space. That is, in an event of a failover, it will use the Azure VNet Address space. You can only keep the same IP Address if the Azure Vnet which ASR is configured is isolated so that you replicate the same networking scenario as on-prem.

2) If you have S2S, I'd advise deploying a new DC instead. Although possible, DC doesn't play well with ASR as you need to keep everything exactly the same when failing over and that's most of the time no possible. Assuming an isolated network, the DC replica in Azure will be configured for at least 2 cores (so that you may have up to 4 disks) and 3 disks exactly like on-prem (1 OS, 2 Data disks I assume).

3) Again, assuming an isolated DR network in Azure, after failover, you can connect the two sites in Azure through S2S or VNet Peering. Because on-prem and Azure DR network have the same IP Address space, you won't be able to keep this integration online before failover, although I'm thinking it should be possible to have the DR site in Azure as a failover for your S2S VPN. See here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-highlyavailable

**Update:**

Additional details about retaining IP addresses during failover:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/concepts-on-premises-to-azure-networking

> - If the IP address pool in the secondary site is the same as that on the source site, Site Recovery allocates the same IP address (of the
>     source VM), to the replica VM.
> - If the same IP address isn't available, Site Recovery allocates another available IP address from the pool.
> - If VMs use DHCP, Site Recovery doesn't manage the IP addresses. You need to check that the DHCP server on the secondary site can allocate
>     addresses from the same range as the source site.

To verify the IP Address of the failover VM in Site Recovery:

````
```
$vm = Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name <VM_NAME>
$na = $vm[0].VirtualNetworkAdapters>
$ip = Get-SCIPAddress -GrantToObjectID $na[0].id
$ip.address 
```
````

You can also override that and run a PowerShell script during failover to set whatever IP you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 1) The whole idea of replicating on-premises DC to Azure is to replicate the existing scenario where Azure site and On-premises site are two separates AD sites. My understanding is that if I create 172.28.0.0/16 network then AD would retain its IP if failover occurs. 2) It still unclear if replicated VM retains its hardware configuration and if yes, how it is configured. 3) As you could see on the diagram, at the moment there is a S2S IPsec VPN tunnel between Azure Virtual Network Gateway and On-premises firewall. Once disaster recovery occurs, AD on Azure s

Comment: Did I answer the questions? Anything else you need to clarify?

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for your reply. For now I use Virtual Network Gateway to connect on-premises site and Azure site. When failover occurs, both sites will be on Azure and they should be connected with VNet-to-VNet connection. Now question is, how do I switch between S2S IPsec VPN and VNet2VNet connections?

Comment: I guess the best option is to make the Azure site the failover path in your azure vnet gateway. Using a standard gateway you may have active-active or active-passive configurations so that if one link goes down the other will take over. In your case, active-passive may be the best option, but you gonna have to use S2S VPN to connect Azure to Azure instead of VNet peering. I'm not aware of any ways to create an active-passive using both S2S and Vnet Peering. You can have both connected at the same time, but as long as the network routes are not overlapping which is not the case.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have a couple of on-premises virtual servers for which traffic from outside is redirected via port forwarding configured on the router. I want the same once failover occurs and replicated virtual machines startup on Azure. How to configure Port Forwarding on Azure?

Comment: You have to use a load balancer and configure inbound NAT rules. You can either create the LB beforehand or create during failover. There's something called Recovery Plan that you can use to run PowerShell scripts prior to VM boot or during deployment. That's how you automate processes, configures VMs beyond the basics or deploy new components that are required for your servers to failover properly. This avoids several manual steps after you failover to Azure.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Let just clarify once again. Here is what I have regarding the infrastructure. 1) On-premises site in Sydney datacenter where I have 3 Hyper-V virtual machines DC, RD Gateway and Remote Session Host in subnet 172.28.0.0/16. 2) Azure site (Honk Kong) where I have 2 machines DC, Remote Session Host in subnet 172.25.0.0/24. 3) Both on-prem and Azure sites comprise two-site domain and connected by means of Site-to-Site IPSec VPN tunnel.

Comment: I would like, in case Hyper-V host or Datacenter disaster, three on-prem workloads recover on dedicated Azure site (geographically located in Australia) with connection restored between recovered site and existing Azure site (located in Hong Kong). I’ m just wondering if that disaster recovery plan could be realized in Azure.